# Has anyone looked at the percent of brilliant, best, book, etc moves in chess.com by rating?

Tags: analysis, rating, statistics, blunder, chess.com

After a game, chess.com lists moves as "brilliant", "best" etc down to "blunder". I'm wondering about the % of each for random selections of players at different levels is.

Answer (score 3):

[Chess.com](https://www.chess.com) has a feature called [Insights](https://www.chess.com/insights) which allows you to view many statistics about a player(for different time controls) like their score vs various openings, win % during different times of the day/week, geography, tactics found/missed etc.

It also allows you to view the quality of a player's moves, including the number & percentage of brilliant, blunder, mistakes, inaccuracy and book moves.

**Note**: It's a paid feature of [Chess.com](https://www.chess.com). So, if you have a [Diamond Membership](https://www.chess.com/membership) on their platform, you can access this Insights feature for any user(they need to have a diamond membership for their account too!) on their platform.
Some insights of top players/streamers(with a rating range of 3200 to 1100) are available which you can access for **free**.

Here's the number of brilliant moves from [GM Hikaru's Insights](https://www.chess.com/insights/hikaru#quality):
[image]

Comment: Thanks.  That will be useful to answer the question, if no one has answered it already.